# Clojure, core.logic, mini-kanren: eqo vs ==

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I'm aware of: https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/wiki/Differences-from-The-Reasoned-Schemer

### Context

mini-kanren code:

```
(run* (q)
  (eqo pear plum)
  (== #t q))
```

core.logic code

```
(run* [q]
  (== pear plum)
  (== true q))
```

This produces the result (), which is the correct answer.

### Question:

Is eqo and == the same, or did I just lucky in the above example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember correctly eqo just calls ==

Comment: yeah, it's basically (defn ego [x y] (== x y))